# How to create same-side dual y-axis plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, axis

I have four columns of data x, y1, y2, type, where x, y1, y2 are numerical values, and type is a classification identifier. I now want to create a double y-axis scatter plot, the y1 axis is above the x axis, and the scale is from the x axis Incrementing upwards, the y2 axis is below the x-axis, and the scale increases downwards from the x-axis. The important thing is that I want these two y-axes to be on the same vertical line, not opposite.

I tried using the sec_axis function in ggplot, but I can't move the y2 axis below the same side as the y1 axis：

```
library(ggplot2)

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

x <- sample(1:11, 10, replace = FALSE)  # Generate random integers from 1 to 11 without replacement
y1 <- sample(10:150, 10, replace = FALSE)  # Generate random numbers from 10 to 150 without replacement
y2 <- sample(10:1500, 10, replace = FALSE)  # Generate random numbers from 10 to 1500 without replacement
type <- sample(c("A", "B", "C"), 10, replace = TRUE)  # Randomly select from "A", "B", "C" with replacement

data <- data.frame(x, y1, y2, type)  # Create a data frame

# Assume data is your data frame with columns x, y1, y2, and type

# Use ggplot function to create a plot object and set the color aesthetic to type in aes function
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y1, fill = type), size = 3, shape = 21) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y2, fill = type), size = 3, shape = 22) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Primary Y-axis",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name = "Secondary Y-axis"),
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 12)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "skyblue", "B" = "blue", "C" = "gray"))

print(p)
```

Below is the plot of the code result (Figure 1). Figure 2 is the plot I hoped to get (I drew it).

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

As you can see, in the Figure 1, the y1 and y2 axis are the same and one of them does not fit the data. How could I fix my code to create figure 2?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to reformat your `y2` data and then manually specify the `y2` axis ticks.  In other words, you could change your `y2` data to be their negative values so that they would be forced to appear below the `y = 0` line.  You would then have to specify your ticks and breaks manually.

Here is an example:

```
#force negative values
data$NegativeY2 <- -data$y2
my.ticks = unique(c(seq(-1200,0, 300), seq(0,150,30)))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = y1, fill = type), size = 3, shape = 21) +
  geom_point(aes(y = NegativeY2, fill = type), size = 3, shape = 22) +
#I specify the limits, breaks, and labels here, inside your scale_y_continuous()
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1200, 150), 
                     breaks = my.ticks,
                     labels = as.character(abs(my.ticks))) +
#I need this to remove clipping for the annotation() steps
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
#Annotation to label the upper y axis
  annotate(geom = "text",
           x = 0,
           y = 30,
           angle = 90,
           label = "Primary Y-axis",
           vjust = -4.5) +
#Annotation to label the lower y axis
  annotate(geom = "text",
           x = 0,
           y = -900,
           angle = 90,
           label = "Secondary Y-axis",
           vjust = -4.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 12)) +
#remove the default y axis label
  labs(y="") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("A" = "skyblue", "B" = "blue", "C" = "gray"))
```

This is a very crude way to do it, and there are definitely better ways to do this apart from `annotate()` to get two labels on the same axis.  Messy code aside, here is what I get:

[image: Plot that makes use of the negative y axis]

Comment: Thank you David! Your solution provided a satisfactory resolution to my data visualization issue. Although there are a few additional adjustments I still need to make, such as aligning the x-axis to y=0 in the vector graphics software (AI) and implementing other modifications. Nevertheless, your solution is adequate for my current requirements. In any case, I will continue to make further modifications to my images using AI.

Comment: Previously, when dealing with this graph, I created separate graphs for x-y1 and x-y2, utilizing the p1/p2 method to position them together on a single graph in a vertical arrangement. This approach allowed me to conveniently modify the subsequent x-axis for both graphs p1 and p2. However, I found this method to lack elegance. I'm intrigued to know if there exists an alternative approach that can satisfy all my needs simultaneously. Your solution has sparked a new idea for me, and I appreciate your insightful response!